# Find all files by extension excluding specific directories

Tags: regex, jestjs, regex-negation

I have both node tests and Angular(4x) tests in the same repository and I am using jest as the test framework. Since both type of tests use different transforms, my idea is to use different jest configurations with different `testRegex`. Below is my folder structure.

```
--e2e
  |-----app.e2e-spec.ts
--src
  --api
    |-----ping.spec.ts
    |-----card.spec.ts
  --util
    |-----util.spec.ts
  --web
    --app
      |-----app.spec.ts
--test.spec.ts
```

In my jest configuration for angular tests, I am using the following regex.

```
"testRegex": "(/src/web/.*\\.spec)\\.ts?$",
```

The idea is to execute all `spec.ts` files under `src/web/` and its subdirectories.

In my jest configuration for node tests, I am using the following regex.

```
"testRegex": "(^((?!.*src/web).).*spec\\.ts.*$)",
```

For my node tests, I want to execute all `spec.ts` files excluding the ones in `src/web` and `e2e/`. My testRegex excludes all files under `src/web`. How can I modify that to add `e2e` also to that regex. Since I'm new to jest, any other suggestions on how to implement this are welcome too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `src/web` in parentheses and add `|e2e/`:

```
"testRegex": "(^((?!.*(src/web|e2e/)).).*spec\\.ts.*$)",
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/ygkmEo/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I definitely tried this one, but I guess I had the * inside parenthesis before src and hence that did not work for me.